# Extract 1 of each property from object

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I am looking for a method using lodash/underscore(or plain JS if one does not exist) that will only me to take a given object such as below.

```
animals: {
  {
    type: 'duck',
    name: 'quack',
  },
  {
    type: 'duck',
    name: 'quieck',
  },
  {
    type: 'dog',
    name: 'bark',
  },
},
```

This object for example contains 3 different animals, but two of them are the same type.

The end result is to be able to use a control structure such as a for loop to iterate through each TYPE of animal, such that I'm working with something that only has one instance of each type.

This is being used because I am creating a list.

This list will be similar to the following

```
duck
 name is quack
 name is quick
dog
 name is bark
```

But i want to do this with control structures and not by simply outputting and hardcoding in each name, as this list will get very extensive and long.

Comment: Shouldn't `animals` actually be an array, not an object?

Comment: Is annimal an `Array`, or an `object`?

Comment: That's true, but my question still applies to that case as well, I'm jsut trying to extract 1 instance of each type from all of the objects. sorry about the confusion

Comment: Animal is an object. it's a json object output

Comment: If it's an object, it's an invalid object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the uniq function.

```
var uniqueAnimals = _.uniq(animals, function(item, key, type) { 
    return item.type;
});
```

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Presuming `animals` is not a syntax error, but an array: If you don't just want to filter the unique types but also create a structure for your output, you could go with an object:

```
var kv = {};
animals.forEach(function(a) {
    if(kv[a.type]) {
        kv[a.type].push(a.name);
    } else {
        kv[a.type] = [];
    } 
}
```

Later, you could iterate `Object.keys(kv)` to print your key/values

Answer (score 0):

[_.groupBy()](https://lodash.com/docs#groupBy) maybe?

```js
var animals = [
  {
    type: 'duck',
    name: 'quack',
  },
  {
    type: 'duck',
    name: 'quieck',
  },
  {
    type: 'dog',
    name: 'bark',
  },
];
  
var grouped = _.groupBy(animals, 'type');

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(grouped, null, 3) + '</pre>');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.6.1/lodash.min.js"></script>
```